# How to check if a file exists in Google Storage from Spark Dataproc?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I was assuming that Google Storage connector would allow to query GS directly as if it was HDFS from Spark in Dataproc, but it looks like the following does not work (from Spark Shell):

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

scala> FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path("gs://samplebucket/file"))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: gs://samplebucket/file, expected: hdfs://dataprocmaster-m
```

Is there a way to access Google Storage files using just the Hadoop API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `FileSystem.get(...)` returns the default `FileSystem` which according to your configuration is `HDFS` and can only work with paths starting with `hdfs://`. Use the following to get the correct FS.

```
Path p = new Path("gs://...");
FileSystem fs = p.getFileSystem(...);
fs.exists(p);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked ok just by obtaining the file system like this: `path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration)`

Answer (score 5):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val p = "gs://<your dir>"

val path = new Path(p)
val fs = path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.exists(path)

fs.isDirectory(path)
```

Comment: The code is in Scala it works standalone and it is a direct answer to the question how to check if a file exists

Answer (score 0):

I translated @Pradeep Gollakota answer to PySpark, thanks!!

```
def path_exists(spark, path): #path = gs://.... return true if exists 
    p = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path)
    fs = p.getFileSystem(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
    return fs.exists(p)
```