# Check if Google storage bucket or file exists using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to check if a Google storage bucket exists using spark-scala. If it doesn't exist, create it.

Can somebody help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, do you want to check if a bucket or a file exists? Those are different things. In any case, you can use the [Java client library for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage) from Scala.

Answer (score 1):

To access Google Cloud storage bucket, use [Google Cloud Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries):

1. To check if bucket exist, use [get_bucket method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python) and it is also possible to access [bucket metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata)
2. To create new bucket, use [create_bucket method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-python)

Please note, that in order to read/write to the bucket, there is a need to [set proper permissions for the storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-reference)

---

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a given google cloud storage exists, then if it does not exist create an empty dataframe and overwrite the path plus a folder so spark creates a bucket with a folder inside and then make spark delete the folder.

I made it with PySpark but you can easily translate it to Scala with the help of the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079970/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-google-storage-from-spark-dataproc/72370422#72370422).

```
p = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path)
fs = p.getFileSystem(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

if fs.exists(p) == False:
    df = #Create an empty dataframe
    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("gs://...../folder")
    fs.delete("gs://..../folder", True)
```